# multiple uses of multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm trying to create a table in LaTeX using the `multirow` package that is such that we have in the first column, a row that spans six (with a title/whatever in it) with an empty space in the top row, then in the next column, I want to have a top row, then beneath it, 3 sub rows that each span two rows, and then have the remaining columns as normal.

Here is my attempt at a table (with blank spaces for where my data will be entered)

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-7}
                                             &                    & & & & & \\ \cline{1-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }  \multirow{6}{*}{$T$} & \multirow{2}{*}{1} & & & & & \\ \cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }                       &                    & & & & & \\ \cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }                       & \multirow{2}{*}{2} & & & & & \\ \cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }                       &                    & & & & & \\ \cline(2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }                       & \multirow{2}{*}{3} & & & & & \\ \cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }                       &                    & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

but I keep getting the error

```
argument of \xmultirow has an extra }'.
```

The `\multicolumn` use is so that I can have lines in the appropriate places

I've searched through a lot of questions on here, and documents but found nothing with a specific double use.

Comment: you have a wrong parentheses `(` instead of `{` at the fifth row. If you put the correct one, put the `\multirow{6}` inside `{}` and add `{}` after `\multicolumn{}{}` your code compiles

Answer (score 3):

as stated in my previous comment, you need to fix the code so that it can be compiled. Your (fixed) code produces this:
[image]

but I think you want this:
[image]

which can be obtained with the following adjustements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-7}
                                             &                    & & & & & \\ \cline{1-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{\multirow{6}{*}{$T$}} & \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{\multirow{2}{*}{1}} & & & & & \\ \cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{}                       &                    & & & & & \\ \cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                       & \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{\multirow{2}{*}{2}} & & & & & \\ \cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{}                       &                    & & & & & \\ \cline{2-7}
 \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                       & \multicolumn{1}{ |c|  }{\multirow{2}{*}{3}} & & & & & \\ \cline{3-7}
 \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{}                       &                    & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```