# Multiple uses of multirow in LaTeX

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm trying to create a table in LaTeX using the [`multirow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow/) package that is such that we have in the first column, a row that spans six (with a title/whatever in it) with an empty space in the top row, then in the next column, I want to have a top row, then beneath it, 3 sub rows that each span two rows, and then have the remaining columns as normal.

Here is my attempt at a table (with blank spaces for where my data will be entered)

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-7}
                                             &                    & & & & & \\ \cline{1-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }  \multirow{6}{*}{$T$} & \multirow{2}{*}{1} & & & & & \\ \cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }                       &                    & & & & & \\ \cline{2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }                       & \multirow{2}{*}{2} & & & & & \\ \cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }                       &                    & & & & & \\ \cline(2-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }                       & \multirow{2}{*}{3} & & & & & \\ \cline{3-7}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }                       &                    & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

but I keep getting the error

```
argument of \xmultirow has an extra }
```

The multicolumn use is so that I can have lines in the appropriate places.

I've searched through a lot of questions on here, and documents but found nothing with a specific double use.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that existed as google always took me to this site :P. I searched through it before I reposted my question too.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Change your username to something more telling than "user2285541".

Comment: Perhaps we can already close this one as the OP has already asked the very same question earlier in [multiple uses of multirow](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108982/multiple-uses-of-multirow)